# How to return JSON by rendering razor syntax in to string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am following the tutorial in which the instructor create a class for converting razor syntax to string which is right bellow .

```
 public static string RazorToString(Controller controller , string viewName , object model = null)
        {
            controller.ViewData.Model = model;
            using(var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult;
                viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

In the controller action he return the jSON like this.

```
return Json(new { success = true, html = RazorViewToString.RazorToString(this,"GetAll" ,), message = "submitted succesfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The **GetALL** is the action method which he passed , which is returning the list of records. which is right below.

```
 public ActionResult GetAll()
        {
            using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
            {
                var list = db.Employees.ToList();
                return View(list);
            }
        }
```

This above method is the difference I mean in that tutorial the instructor has separately created a method which is getting the list and in this action method he called that method.but in my implementation i returing the list directly as you can seen above.so in the third parameter of

```
RazorViewToString.RazorToString(this,"GetAll" ,)
```

He passed that method which i not created , what i supposed to pass here ? and also if someone can describe the functionality above i will be thankful to him. #Peace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is not the method name,but the view name.The third parameter is the view model/model needed for that view.

Looks like your `GetAll.cshtml` view is strongly typed to a list of `Employees`. So you should be passing that as the model parameter value.

```
var employeeList = db.Employees.ToList();
return Json(new { success = true,
                  html = RazorToString(this, "GetAll",employeeList ), 
                  message = "submitted succesfully" },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This will call the `RazorToString` method and inside the method we are manually executing the razor view engine and it will return a string which is the HTML markup produced by the view. We are then creating an anonymous object with 3 properties `success`, `html` and `message` and passing that to the Json method, which will convert it to corresponding json format.